# w3IncludeHTML sometimes includes twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short HTML file that tries to add a one-line footer that will be common to several files by using `w3IncludeHTML`. Some of the time, it works, but some of the time the last bit of HTML before the call to `w3IncludeHTML` is replaced by the footer, with the end result being that the last bit is missing and the footer appears twice.

Here's my calling page:

```
<head>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="lessons.html">&laquo;  Previous</a> &bull; <a href="home.html"> Home </a> 

<div w3-include-html="Footer.html"></div>

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
```

Here's my footer page:

```
Footer.
```

When it works, my output looks like this:

```
« Previous • Home
Footer.
```

When it doesn't work, it looks like this:

```
« Previous •
Footer.
Footer.
```

There is no way I have found to force either behavior. Whether it works or not appears to be at random, with the error coming and going as I refresh the page over and over.

I'm using Chrome 53.0.2785.143 m and running Apache HTTP Server 2.4.7 as my localhost under Windows 10 Version 1607 Build 14393.321. (Problem may well be a Chrome issue, as IE11, FireFox 49, and Edge don't show the same behavior.)

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I pulled out the JavaScript function's source and played with that a bit. The problem goes away if, at the point where the function opens an `XMLHttpRequest`, it asks for the subsequent `send` operation to be synchronous. This doesn't appear to be a real fix, though, as synchronous use of `send` is deprecated on the main thread. I'm no JavaScript guru, so I'm don't understand why making this operation asynchronous would cause the problem I am seeing. Is it a bug in Chrome, maybe?

Here's the JavaScript (please note I have changed the name of the function and the name of the attribute it looks for, and reformatted it a bit; other than that, it is that same as w3schools' version, but for the change from `true` to `false` in the call to the `open` method):

```
function xLuIncludeFile()
{
  var z, i, a, file, xhttp;

  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++)
  {
    if (z[i].getAttribute("xlu-include-file"))
    {
      a = z[i].cloneNode(false);
      file = z[i].getAttribute("xlu-include-file");
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
          a.removeAttribute("xlu-include-file");
          a.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
          z[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, z[i]);
          xLuIncludeFile();
        }
      }      

      // false makes the send operation synchronous, which solves a problem
      // when using this function in short pages with Chrome. But it is
      // deprecated on the main thread due to its impact on responsiveness.
      // This call may end up throwing an exception someday.

      xhttp.open("GET", file, false);
      xhttp.send();

      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by installing and enabling the "Chrome Stylist" extension, version 2.1.0. Disabling that extension makes the problem go away.